# How to validate date string in java

Tags: java

How to test a valid date string, assuming acceptable format is "YYYY-MM-DD"? (Y year, M month, D day)

I've tried `DateFormat.parse(date_string)` but it parses things like "2012-542-86".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As default, the parsing is *lenient*, which means it uses heuristics to parse non-exact matches.

You need to turn this off using [#setLenient(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to make it reject all non-matching formats.

Answer (score 2):

The format should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

Have a look at valid formats at [`SimpleDateFormat` API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).